# The gradient of $\| x - \alpha \nabla f(x) \|_2^2$ with respect to $x$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus

> The gradient of $\| x - \alpha \nabla f(x) \|_2^2$ with respect to $x$, where $x \in \mathbb{C}^n$, $\nabla f(x) \in \mathbb{C}^n$, and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$?

---

Following greg's comments, please see below my attempt. Is it correct?

Let us say that $A : B := {\mathrm{Tr}}(A^{\rm T} B)$, $(\cdot)^*$ means complex conjugate, $g := \nabla f$, $H := \nabla g$.

And, $\phi := \| x - \alpha \nabla f(x) \|_2^2 = \| x - \alpha g \|_2^2 = \left(x - \alpha g \right) : \left(x - \alpha g \right)^*$.

Then, ignoring the non-conjugate term in the differential,
\begin{align}
d \phi 
&= \left(x - \alpha g \right) : d\left(x - \alpha g \right)^*\\
&= \left(x - \alpha g \right) : \left(dx^* - \alpha \, H^* dx^* \right) \\
&= \left(I - \alpha H^* \right)^{\rm T}\left(x - \alpha g \right) : dx^*
\end{align}

So, the gradient is
$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^*} = \left(I - \alpha H^* \right)^{\rm T}\left(x - \alpha g \right) = \left(I - \alpha H^{\rm H} \right)\left(x - \alpha \nabla f \right)$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Instead of repeatedly using nabla, give names to the gradient $(g=\nabla f)$ and Hessian $(H=\nabla g)$. Then you can say things like $df=g:dx+g^*:dx^*$ and $dg=H\,dx+H^*\,dx^*$. The problem with $\nabla^2f$ is that it will be confused with a Laplacian, which is a scalar rather than a matrix.

Comment: @greg: thank you for the suggestion. Did I understand your suggestion correctly---please see my attempt? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're missing some parentheses on the second line, but otherwise it looks alright. The real issue is the meaning of the gradient when $x\in{\mathbb C}^n$. You might want to check out [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0906.4835.pdf).

Comment: @greg: Thank you so much for your confirmation and also for sharing the paper. I will go through that.